# Как создать объект unique_ptr со структурой внутри класса?

Tags: c++

у меня есть такой класс:

```
template <typename T>
class Store {

private:
    struct pointNode {
        T data;
        std::unique_ptr<pointNode> next;

        pointNode(T n_data,std::unique_ptr<pointNode> ptr) : data(std::move(n_data)), next(std::move(ptr)) {}
    };
    std::unique_ptr<pointNode> head; 
public:
    Store() : head(std::make_unique<pointNode>()) {}
    Store(const T& data);
    Store(const T& data, std::unique_ptr<pointNode> ptr);
    void push(const T& data);

};
```

Я хочу создать временный объект pointNode в функции для хранения :

```
template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T& data) {
    auto temp = std::make_unique<pointNode>(data,nullptr);
    
}
```

Но вылезает ошибка компиляции ,что нет подходящего конструктора по умолчанию. Не могу понять какой еще конструктор нужно сделать, это строчка всегда дает ошибку

```
auto temp = std::make_unique<pointNode>(data,nullptr);
```

Был бы рад помощи ,спасибо.

Comment: *Я хочу создать временный объект pointNode в функции для хранения*  Где вы будете хранить  временный объект? И вообще вы понимаете предназначение умных указателей?  С чего вы взяли, что умный указатель можно создать   с любыми аргументами?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я в функции push хочу добавить элемент в список на который указывает std::unique_ptr<pointNode> head; для этого надо сначала хочу создать temp с переданным значением. Я вот и спросил ,потому что мало работал с умными указателями, но хочу вот так потренироваться и могу не знать тонкостей, когда их нельзя создавать

Answer (score 0):

Компилятор наврал. Ошибка в этой строке.

```
Store() : head(std::make_unique<pointNode>())
```

Можно добавить немного магии и скомпилит:

```
Store() : head(std::make_unique<pointNode>(T{}, std::unique_ptr<pointNode>{}))
```

Comment: ,не очень понял что не так ,но ваше исправление ,вроде как, помогло .Спасибо

Comment: У pointNode нет конструктора без параметров. А значит для создания unique pointNode надо передать параметры конструктора. А вообще куда логичнее было бы написать  Store() {}, но это уже совсем другая история.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже указано в смежном ответе, ошибка должна ссылаться на конструкцию `std::make_unique<pointNode>()` по причине отсутствия у `pointNode` конструктора по умолчанию. И здесь есть несколько путей решения:

1. Использовать имеющийся конструктор с двумя аргументами (уже показали)
2. Добавить конструктор по умолчанию (самое простое сделать это через `= default`)
3. Удалить имеющийся конструктор (сделав тем самым класс `pointNode` агрегатным классом). Необходимые `std::move` можно будет делать прямо по месту.

В третьем случае, если понадобится выполнять создание `unique_ptr` для инициализации отдельных членов как, например, в `std::make_unique<pointNode>(data, nullptr);`, то надо либо переходить на C++20 (там `make_unique` работает для агрегатов), либо для C++14/17 использовать следующую запись `std::unique_ptr<pointNode>(new pointNode{data, nullptr});`